# checkboxinput overlaid on the label

Tags: django, checkbox, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I am working with a form in django with crispy form and it has many fields, and the checkboxinput field does not render well in the html, it is overlapped in the label and very big.
previously i was using another template style but when i changed the html, the checks were broken

```
form.py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test

fields = [
            'test1',
            'test2'
         ]

        labels = {
            'test1':'Test 1',
            'test2':'Test 2',}

widgets = {
            'test1':forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-label'}),
            'test2':forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-label'}),
```

```
form.html
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center pt-4 pl-2">
    {{ form.test1 | as_crispy_field }}                         
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center pt-4 pl-2">
    {{ form.test2 | as_crispy_field }}                        
  </div>
```

[This is how the checkboxes and the labels look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeY38.png)